# Best cross-platform alignment macro?

Tags: c

```
__declspec(align(X))
__attribute((aligned(X)))
```

These are the two I've come across. Are they the only two ways that compilers deal with alignment?

If I target C11, will `alignas(X)` accomplish the same thing and is it implemented in all C11 supporting compilers? On macOS using clang it seems `alignas(X)` doesn't work with typedefs?

```
typedef alignas(16) float vec4[4];
error: '_Alignas' attribute only applies to variables and fields
        ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is *not* with your clang on macOS but with the other compiler(s) allowing `alignas()` (actually a macro for `_Alignas()` in C)<sup>1</sup> on the `typedef` (presumably, as an extension).

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas) (bolding mine):

> The `_Alignas` specifier can only be used when declaring objects that
> aren't bit fields, and don't have the register storage class. It
> cannot be used in function parameter declarations, **and cannot be
> used in a typedef**.

Or, from [this Draft C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> ##### 6.7.5 Alignment specifier
>
> …
> **Constraints**
> 2     An alignment attribute shall not be specified in a declaration of a `typedef`, or a bit-field, or a function, or a parameter, or an object declared with the **`register`** storage-class specifier.

---

<sup>1</sup> The `alignas` keyword was introduced **to C++** at the C++11 Standard; ISO C11 added it as an 'alias' of the `_Alignas` keyword. From the [cppreference for the C++ version](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas):

> As of the ISO C11 standard, the C language has the `_Alignas` keyword
> and defines `alignas` as a preprocessor macro expanding to the keyword
> in the header `<stdalign.h>`.

Comment: Interestingly, in C++ `alignas` **can** be used in a `typedef` - https://godbolt.org/z/vYW73519M

Comment: @DanielKleinstein Not sure about that (I'll need to check the standard). But, compiling OP's line with clang-cl (in Visual Studio) and using the C++17 standard, I get: *error : an attribute list cannot appear here*

Comment: Yes, OP's example has the `alignas` in the wrong place in the typedef - if you move it to the end of the line it should compile

Comment: Though perhaps this is gcc-specific - it doesn't compile on clang.

Comment: @DanielKleinstein Nope! Then I get: *error : 'alignas' attribute cannot be applied to types*. Looks like it's a GCC extension. Try your godbolt with clang...

Comment: Yes.. interesting that it works with gcc in C++ but not in C.

Comment: MSVC gives: *error C2024: 'alignas' attribute applies to variables, data members and tag types only* (in C++17).